# how to check if a string exists in an array of strings

Tags: php

I have data stored in a string: such as `$string='12';`
'12' represents 2 pieces of data, `1` and `2`

In 3 columns, I have those same ids stored,  the array comes out as :

```
ex1: $array= ('num1' => 1, 'num2' => 2, 'num3' => )
ex2: $array= ('num1' => 5, 'num2' => 4, 'num3' => 3)
```

How could I compare these and return true if the numbers exist in both places?

For instance: using the above example:
for ex1:
`12` would `return TRUE`

`34` would `return FALSE`
for ex2:
`345` would `return TRUE`

Comment: Why does `34` return FALSE?

Comment: 12 and 34 are for example 1 and 345 is for example2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This works, please see results below: (Value must be present in both array to return true.**

```
  $result = true;
    $string1 = '43';
    $string = str_split($string1);
    $example1 = array('num1' => 1, 'num2' => 2, 'num3' => 3,  'num4' => 4, 'num5' => 5);
    $example2 = array('num1' => 5, 'num2' => 4, 'num3' => 3);
    foreach ($string as $st) {
        if((in_array($st, $example1) && in_array($st, $example2))  && $result == true){
            $result = true; //true
        } else {
            $result = false;
        }
    }
    if($result == true){
            echo 1; //true
        } else {
            echo 0; //false
        }
    exit;
    //Test Results:
    //$string1 = '12'; //result 0
    //$string1 = '34'; //result 1
    //$string1 = '55'; //result 1
    //$string1 = '43'; //result 1
```

Answer (score 1):

try this: You can use **array_intersect**().

```
$string = '12';

//split string into array of characters
$arr = str_split($string);

//testing columns
$compare1 = array('num1' => 1, 'num2' => 2, 'num3' => '');
$compare2 = array('num1' => 5, 'num2' => 4, 'num3' => 3);

//returns an array containing all the values of $arr inside $compare1
$int1 = array_intersect($arr, $compare1);

//returns an array containing all the values of $arr inside $compare2
$int2 = array_intersect($arr, $compare2);

//if $arr contents are in $compare1 return true, otherwise false
echo ! empty($int1);

//if $arr contents are in $compare2 return true, otherwise false
echo ! empty($int2);
```

Answer (score 1):

try in_array() function 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php

but I don't understand why 345 would return true

Comment: because array2 contains 3, 4 and 5

Comment: yeah i apologize. IT was written confusing.  The first 2 `return` examples were directed at example 1. and the last was directed at example 2

Comment: true, but he said if $string exists in both places

Comment: in_array wouldnt work by the way since what he is trying to search is string and not array. Unless you convert it to array

Comment: he has an array,  and a string to search for.  yes it will work.  not as nice as your intersect method,  but yes it will.  split his original string into parts and check in_array for each part...

Comment: yes that if you split it but you suggested to use in_array without mentioning to use split

Comment: he already knows he needs to split it or get each character of $string to check for. I answered the question on how to search for in array

Answer (score 1):

I'm late to the party... but I had already started, so might as well!  Here's my solution:

```
function yayOrNay($array, $string) {

    $stringArray = str_split($string);

    $arrayDiff = array_diff($stringArray, array_values($array));

    return empty($arrayDiff);
}
```

<kbd>**[LIVE DEMO](http://codepad.org/Ymw9fbdc)**</kbd>